# Problem with findAllAsync() android webview

Tags: javascript, android, search, webview, highlight

I need to implement "highlight searched text" in webview. I did this, however, there is a slight problem...
There should be only one color(yellow) but there is also a second color(orange). And I can't find a way to override the color.

Also, if there is no way to do that. Can you tell me what to do? Because I have heard javascript option but I can't make it work

```
traffic_rules_comment?.text=commentText
webview?.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
webview?.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
titleTextView?.text= learningMaterials.name
webview?.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, learningMaterials.description, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
webview?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
webview.webViewClient = mWebViewClient
loader?.visibility = VISIBLE
number?.text = learningMaterials.number
webview.findAllAsync(searchText)
```

Comment: can you provide a code snippet ? can you describe the technologies you use ?

Comment: @EvaCohen,updated